# Python - comparing sublists within two different lists

Tags: python, list, comparison, sublist

I have two lists, each containing sublists in the form [chromosome, start_position, end_position]:

```
expos_list = [['1', '10', '30'], ['1', '50', '80'], ['1', '100', '200']]  
pos_list = [['1', '12', '25'], ['1', '90', '98'], ['1', '130', '180'], ['2', '25', '50']]
```

I want to compare the sublists in 'pos_list' to the sublists in 'expos_list' and then add a 'pos_list' element to 'expos_list' if it is unique and/or is not contained within another expos_list element. So I would like my final output to be:

```
expos_list = [['1', '10', '30'], ['1', '50', '80'], ['1', '90', '98'], ['1', '100', '200'], ['2', '25', '50']]
```

...as this has only unique position ranges for each particular chromosome (chromosome = sublist[0] in both cases).

I have tried:

```
for expos_element in expos_list:
    for pos_element in pos_list:
        if pos_element[0] == expos_element[0]:
            if pos_element[1] < expos_element[1]:
                if pos_element[2] < expos_element[1]:
                    print("New")
                elif pos_element[2] < expos_element[2]:
                print("Overlapping at 3'")
                else:
                print("Discard")
            elif expos_element[1] <= pos_element[1] < expos_element[2]:
                if pos_element[2] <= expos_element[2]:
                print("Discard")
                else:
                print("Overlapping at 5'")
            else:
            print("Hit is 3' of current existing element. Move on")
        else:
        print("Different chromosome")
```

Which obviously doesn't do the append to list bit etc, but is specifying whether there is an overlap of the elements. It does this, but compares all elements all the time, giving this output:

```
Discard
Hit is 3' of current existing element. Move on
Discard
Different chromosome
New
Hit is 3' of current existing element. Move on
New
Different chromosome
Overlapping at 5'
Hit is 3' of current existing element. Move on
Discard
Different chromosome
```

This gives 12 lines of output (rather than the desired one line per sublist in pos_list). I'm really struggling to get this working. I guess my ideal output for the above run would be:

```
Discard
New
Discard
Different chromosome
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The two outputs sections I've written are just to the screen as standard output - also apologies for any dodgy if/else blocks in the code - didn't quite get the hang of the formatting on here (the blocks are all correctly tabbed out in my editor)

Comment: Why not just remove the unneeded `print` calls? You are getting 12 prints because any branch your code gets into contains a print call. And since you are iterating over all elements of `pos_list` for each element of `expos_list`, you're getting `4x3=12` output lines.

Comment: @kroolik - yeah, the prints are just there for testing. This issue isn't the fact that it is printing - the code is iterating over each sublist of expos_list for all sublists of pos_list. This means that even if a sublist has been defined as 'discard' it may be considered as 'new' on the next iteration when being compared to a different sublist.

Comment: That's the point, you are not removing element marked as `Discard` from the `pos_list`. Same for different chromosome case.

Comment: `['1', '130', '180']` is discarded because it's included in `['1', '100', '200']` ? Am i right in assuming, tht the first number is the chromosom and the following pair are the number s of the starting and stopping pairs?

Comment: @DonQuestion, Yes, it's in the first sentence of the question :P

Comment: ... <awkward silence> ;-) Overlaps not fully contained are being kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not that interested in how each item overlaps, simplify the code to your three cases (discard, new, different):

```
new_items = []
for item in pos_list:
    if not any(x[0] == item[0] for x in expos_list):
        print("Different chromosome")
        new_items.append(item)
    elif any(x[1] < item[1] < x[2] or x[1] < item[2] < x[2]
             for x in expos_list):
        print("Discard")
    else:
        print("New")
        new_items.append(item)
expos_list.extend(new_items)
print(expos_list)
```

When I run it, I see:

```
Discard
New
Discard
Different chromosome
[['1', '10', '30'], ['1', '50', '80'], ['1', '100', '200'], ['1', '90', '98'], ['2', '25', '50']]
```

Comment: To extend the code though - how would you adapt it so that it could also register those sequences that overlapped with existing elements in expos_list? And, what if an item in expos_list was completely contained within a larger pos_list element?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "register". For the latter case, you could add `elif any(x[1] < item[1] and x[2] < item[2] for ...):`, but it depends what you want to do in that case.

Comment: Also - if the scale expands (which it will) this code will fall down when there a hits on many different chromosomes - if any of these overlap with other chromosome hits then they won't be added, even if they are technically unique...

Comment: I can only deal with the cases I know about! If you will have multiple chromosomes, I would suggest a different data structure, perhaps: `{1:[(10,30), (50,80), ...], 2: [(25,50)]}` so you can easily choose hits for the appropriate chromosome.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'register' as in - record those positions. So if I had an element which was ['1', '150', '900'] and one that was ['1', '899', '999'] I would also want to append this hit to the expos_list as it is of interest (and not merge them).    Second, cool, thank you. If it was totally contained within a new larger item I would just want to add the larger one to the expos_list as well. Not replace the original (now contained element) or anything.

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate discussion - you are adding lots of extra cases not in the question, my answer only covers those you mentioned initially. Generally, you need to think about what your cases are (e.g. what is an overlap "of interest"; 1? 5? 10?) and write an `elif` block for each one, `append`ing what you want to keep to `new_items`.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry - didn't mean to badger you. I've just been stuck on this for a while and was excited to be making progress! Thank you so much for your help. I will keep thinking on this!

Comment: No problem, hope my comments so far help you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I've separated it out a bit; try

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import bisect_left

class ChromoSegments:
    def __init__(self, cs=None):
        # A list of [(start, end), (start, end), ...] per chromosome;
        #   each list is kept sorted in ascending order
        self.segments = defaultdict(list)

        # Add segments from parameter list
        if cs is not None:
            for chromo,start,end in cs:
                try:
                    self.add_seg(chromo, start, end)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

    def add_seg(self, chromo, start, end):
        seg = self.segments[chromo]
        val = (start, end)
        ndx = bisect_left(seg, val)
        if (ndx == 0 or seg[ndx - 1][1] < start):
            if (ndx == len(seg) or end < seg[ndx][0]):
                seg.insert(ndx, val)
            else:
                # collision with following element
                nstart, nend = seg[ndx]
                raise ValueError('Discard ({}, {}, {}): collision with ({}, {}, {})'.format(chromo, start, end, chromo, nstart, nend))
        else:
            # collision with preceding element
            nstart, nend = seg[ndx - 1]
            raise ValueError('Discard ({}, {}, {}): collision with ({}, {}, {})'.format(chromo, start, end, chromo, nstart, nend))

    def to_list(self):
        keys = sorted(self.segments.keys())
        return [(k, s, e) for k in keys for s,e in self.segments[k]]

def main():
    expos = ChromoSegments([[1, 10, 30], [1, 50, 80], [1, 100, 200]])
    pos = [[1, 12, 25], [1, 90, 98], [1, 130, 180], [2, 25, 50]]

    target_chromo = 1
    for seg in pos:
        if seg[0] != target_chromo:
            print('Different chromosome')
        else:
            try:
                expos.add_seg(*seg)
                print('New')
            except ValueError, e:
                print(e.message)

    print('\nResult: {}'.format(expos.to_list()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which produces

```
Discard (1, 12, 25): collision with (1, 10, 30)
New
Discard (1, 130, 180): collision with (1, 100, 200)
Different chromosome

Result: [(1, 10, 30), (1, 50, 80), (1, 90, 98), (1, 100, 200)]
```

Note that I wrote the class to properly deal with multiple chromosomes; the 'different chromosome' warning had to be handled separately in main().

**Edit:**

If you want to deal with multiple chromosomes, `main()` can be simplified like so:

```
def main():
    expos = ChromoSegments([[1, 10, 30], [1, 50, 80], [1, 100, 200]])
    pos = [[1, 12, 25], [1, 90, 98], [1, 130, 180], [2, 25, 50]]

    for seg in pos:
        try:
            expos.add_seg(*seg)
            print('New')
        except ValueError, e:
            print(e.message)

    print('\nResult: {}'.format(expos.to_list()))
```

and the output becomes

```
Discard (1, 12, 25): collision with (1, 10, 30)
New
Discard (1, 130, 180): collision with (1, 100, 200)
New

Result: [(1, 10, 30), (1, 50, 80), (1, 90, 98), (1, 100, 200), (2, 25, 50)]
```

Comment: So the different chromosome hit [2, 25, 50] is ignored? As it doesn't end up in your final Result: ....

Comment: aww, was considering something similar, but i didn't think of bisect! +1 for that ;-)

Comment: @HughBothwell - thanks for the edit! I'm new to object oriented python (and pretty new to Python in general) so I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what is happening! Is there any chance of a few more comment lines inside each defined method?
Also, how would I incorporate including segments that overlap into my list? Exclude segments that are totally inclusive - such as (1, 130, 180) within (1, 100, 200) - but include those that overlap for later quality checking - such as (1, 100, 200) and (1, 190, 300). I know this extends the question, but any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This one generates a range from the starting and end points of your DNA snippets and
simply checks if the positions in a new snippet already exist in the existing ranges.
Multiple chromosomes taken care of by `dict` as suggested by someone else.

```
class DNASegments():
    def __init__(self, segments):
        segments = self._convert(segments)
        self.segments = {}
        for s in segments:
            self.add_segment(s)

    def add_segment(self, s):
        chromosome = s[0]
        positions = range(s[1], s[2]+1)

        if not chromosome in self.segments.keys():
            self.segments[chromosome] = []

        if not any([p in range(ps[0], ps[1]+1) for ps\
                    in self.segments[chromosome] for p in positions]):
            self.segments[chromosome].append([s[1], s[2]])

        self._sort()

    def add_list(self, segments):
        segments = self._convert(segments)
        for s in segments:
            self.add_segment(s)
        self._sort()

    def _convert(self,segments):
        return [[int(s[0]), int(s[1]), int(s[2])] for s in segments]
    def _sort(self):
        for key in self.segments.keys():
            self.segments[key] = sorted(self.segments[key])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.segments)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.segments)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.segments[i]



expos_list = [['1', '10', '30'], ['1', '50', '80'], ['1', '100', '200']]  
pos_list = [['1', '12', '25'], ['1', '90', '98'], ['1', '130', '180'], 
            ['2', '25', '50']]

dnaseg = DNASegments(expos_list)

dnaseg
>>> {1: [[10, 30], [50, 80], [100, 200]]}

dnaseg.add_list(pos_list)

dnaseg
>>> {1: [[10, 30], [50, 80], [90, 98], [100, 200]], 2: [[25, 50]]}
```